# Unable to pass string in to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to grab the current value of a search input and then clear the input box on focus, store the string and pass it into a function to re-populate the input box on blur.

```
$("input#search").bind('focus', function() {
    var search_text = document.getElementById('search').value;
    $("input#search").val("");
}).bind('blur', function(search_text) {
    $("input#search").val(search_text);
});
```

Currently, this successfully grabs the value on focus and clears the input box, but on blur, it populates the input with `[object Object]`.

Am I correctly passing the string on line 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `bind()`. It was deprecated a *long* time ago. Use `on()` instead.

With regard to your issue, you can't directly pass a parameter to the anonymous handler function in the manner you're attempting. As it stands your `search_text` variable will hold the `blur` event.

To fix this you could store the variable in a `data` attribute on the `#search` element itself. Try this:

```js
$("input#search").on('focus', function() {
  $(this).data('search-text', this.value).val('');
}).on('blur', function(search_text) {
  $(this).val($(this).data('search-text'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" value="foo bar" />
```

Also, the behaviour you're creating here is similar to the `placeholder` attribute. It may be worth investigating that to see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use .on() of jQuery to register event.

```
var search_text;
$("input#search").on('focus', function() {
   search_text = document.getElementById('search').value;
   $("input#search").val("");
});

$("input#search").on('blur', function() {
   $("input#search").val(search_text);
});
```

Alternate could be ,

```
$("input#search").on('focus', function() {
   var search_text = document.getElementById('search').value;
   $("input#search").val("");

   $(this).on('blur', function() {
     $("input#search").val(search_text);
   });
});
```

Comment: While this may work, I'd suggest avoiding global variables where possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. Here is how you would do, declaring the variable before the event listeners so that it's in the scope:

```
var search_text;
$("input#search").bind('focus', function() {
    search_text = document.getElementById('search').value;
   $("input#search").val("");
}).bind('blur', function() {
   $("input#search").val(search_text);
});
```

The convention in JavaScript for naming variables in Camel Case, so you would rather use `searchText` (not that it really matters).

Comment: Though this still has a global variable